# How to grant more memory to run R processes in SQL Server 2016 R Services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory, r-services

I'm running a fresh install of SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition (13.0.5026.0) with R Services on Windows Server 2016 Standard.  With all sorts of happiness I went to run an R script that completes within 15 mins on my lame desktop machine (8 GB RAM, 1 Intel proc @3.4 GHz) and found that it takes over two hours to run on my carefully configured server.

I'm wondering what else I need to do to get my R processes using more memory?  My script spawns 12 R processes, which sit there using up to 460MB each even though there is plenty available and I've told them to use more.  On my desktop in R Studio this same script happily grabs all available memory.

Here's the relevant details on my setup:

1. 72 GB RAM
2. 2 Intel Xeon procs @ 2.0GHz with 6 cores each
3. SQL Server max memory set to 32 GB (I've also had it at 57.6GB, no difference noted)
4. Though I don't think it matters since I don't have Enterprise Edition w/Resource Governor, I've set the internal and external pools to use 40 and 60 max memory percent, respectively.
5. I have my MAX DOP set at 8 per MS's recommendations, but I've also tried disabling parallel processing by setting this to 1 as I've heard that under certain conditions R's parallel processing can complete with SQL server's.  No change in memory usage by R was seen, but certainly my CPU usage decreased significantly.
6. I've also added a line to the RLauncher config file (E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\rlauncher) to use MEMORY_LIMIT_PERCENT=60.
7. I've confirmed that the SQL Server Service and SQL Server Launchpad services have the correct user rights in the local security policy to replace a process level token, manage memory, etc.
8. Yes, I can successfully run basic R scripts.
9. Yes, I've restarted the server after making my configuration changes.
10. I've ensured that the server is running in high performance mode and not power saving mode in both the BIOS and in Windows.
11. Ensured no errors in the event logs that point to an issue.
12. Ensured that the worker accounts MSSQLSERVER01-20 all have permissions to log on locally and are part of the SQLRUserGroup.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the resource governor.  [Here](https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2016/08/18/resource-governor-and-external-resource-pool-for-microsoft-r-services/) is a good blog.

Enable Resource Governor (do some research on this):

```
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
```

This will tell you how much % of your memory R can use.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.resource_governor_external_resource_pools
```

Sample query to change values from the link:

```
-- Default value
ALTER EXTERNAL RESOURCE POOL [default] 
WITH (AFFINITY CPU = AUTO)
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL RESOURCE POOL RService_Resource_Pool  
WITH (  
     MAX_CPU_PERCENT = 10  
    ,MAX_MEMORY_PERCENT = 5
);  

ALTER RESOURCE POOL [default] WITH (max_memory_percent = 60, max_cpu_percent=90);  
ALTER EXTERNAL RESOURCE POOL [default] WITH (max_memory_percent = 40, max_cpu_percent=10);  
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR reconfigure;
```

Don't forget to run reconfigure again:

```
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
```

Comment: Please see my point #4 above.  Resource Governor is not an available option.

Comment: oh dang, you're right.  Hopefully this answer will help someone else who runs by so I'll leave it up.  Let me think some more about what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Enterprise Edition and want SQL Server to allocate more memory for your R scripts then your only option would be to max out the physical RAM and that way SQL Server can allocate ~20% of that to R services. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/sql-server-configuration-r-services?view=sql-server-2017

Are you consuming data in the R script from SQL Server? If so that could also be creating contention on memory allocation hence causing it to fail on the Server but work fine on your desktop.

Comment: Since I've got 72GB of RAM in total on server and have SQL Server's max memory setting at 57,600MB, I would think that R would get access to 20% of 57,600 = 11,520 GB of RAM.  However, my R processes never use more that 460MB. Yes, I am consuming data in my R script from SQL Server.  But I still never see total server memory utilization over 12% so don't understand why more isn't being used.

Comment: Does R in Standard Edition get 20% of the total memory allocated to SQL Server or 20% of available server memory?

Comment: I’d need to check behaviour on my server but I would guess it gets 20% of the memory allocates to SQL Server, so like you say 11,520GB. However saying that, the screenshots shows your maxing out the CPU - could that be your actual issue? Perhaps batching it up into 2 lots of 6 processes could ease the pressure?

Comment: Also, do you have access to a server running Developer Edition? That way you could test changes in the resource governor to see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I had wondered that too.  I tried limiting this to using 5 processes and I still see the same behavior - 100% CPU usage and no R process using > 460 MB.  I don't have access to developer edition immediately, but it looks like is certainly going to be needed to test this.

Comment: Just for fun I tried limiting my R script to use a single process (par.proc = 1) and see now only ~57% of total processor utilization, and memory utilization stays the same at around 460 MB.  Fascinating!

Comment: How about the run time duration on 5 processes on the server?

Comment: Nearly the same run time duration while using only 5 processes, and only 5 mins longer while using a single process.  I'm new to R / R Services, but I suppose this means that either my R script or the libraries it utilizes does not do multi-threading and is being constrained by CPU because of this.  This is the direction I will now pursue, but please let me know if you see something else here.

Comment: Oh! Did you have the MLK libraries installed on the SQL Server? The SQL Server installer doesn’t bundle them I think.

Comment: Yes, I do have the MLK libraries installed.  That's why this is just so confusing!  If I open R Studio on my server I get these (edited) informational messages:
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Microsoft R Open 3.4.3
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Loading Microsoft R Server packages, version 9.3.0.
Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing(using 12 cores).

Comment: Okay seeing as you have R Studio on the server - what happens if you execute your script directly within R Studio on the server rather than in-database?

Comment: When I run this on the server from within R Studio on my server it behaves the same (100% CPU utilization, < 460 MB used by each R process, on track to take even long than running this through the SQL Server).  It **does** look like all my CPUs are being maxed out, so multi-threading is happening within R.  So I guess my original question still stands but extends perhaps to the version of R I'm using on my server and/or my packages.

Comment: Fascinating. When you run the R script on your desktop - does it pull data from the database server?

Comment: Yes it is the **exact** same script.  But my versions of R are different between my desktop (R version 3.5.0) and versus my database server (R version 3.4.3 with MS R Open 3.4.3 and Intel MKL). Also some of my packages are different but I can't seem to get all the latest with an older version of R as I'm limited to what's available on http://mran.microsoft.com  I guess I'm just having a hard time understanding that the R version/packages would make that much of a difference in processing speed.  My desktop has to pull data across the network and has only 8 GB RAM and 1 Intel proc @3.4 GHz.